# select concrete city from DB

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table city with id and name

for example:

> 1. Münchenbernsdorf
> 2. München
> 3. Berlin
> 4. Moscow

I need to find concrete city.

When I search so `select name from city where LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('München%')`

I get

1. Münchenbernsdorf
2. München

But i want to get München first

1. München
2. Münchenbernsdorf

Comment: What defines a "concrete city"? Don't you need some flag indicating whether or not each row is one of those? Then sort by that flag descending.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT name FROM city WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('München%') ORDER BY LEN(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I would suggest [`ilike`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) for the comparison.  Then you can do:

```
select c.name
from city c
where c.name ilike 'München%'
order by c.name;
```

For your *specific* question (what I think you mean by "concrete"), the ordering by name does what you want because shorter names are ordered -- alphabetically -- before longer names.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5bc604c243c39e0bcdc47da069acfa29) is a db<>fiddle.